# Can I create a new branch for an old commit in BitBucket (Mercurial)?

Tags: mercurial, atlassian-sourcetree

I have tried locating the commit I want to branch from but I cant see any options to create a branch.

I also tried creating a branch but I can't see any way to select an old commit.

This question is related to [my question about pushing a new branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46994416/how-should-i-push-a-new-mercurial-branch-using-sourcetree)

Comment: Do you want to create a branch **from** an old commit or **for** an old commit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### TL;DR

Use `hg update -r <rev>` to check out the revision you want to become the parent of the new branch.  Then, at any time before the next `hg commit`, use `hg branch <new-branch-name>` to record the *name* of the branch you want to create.  Make whatever changes you intend, then run `hg commit` to create a new commit that creates the branch.  The new commit will be the only commit in the new branch, and will be the head (singular) of that branch.

#### Longer description

(Note: I can only answer questions about command line options since I do not use the fancy GUIs.)

In Mercurial, you create a branch by:

1. Using `hg branch` with the branch name:

   ```
   hg branch newbranch
   ```

   Mercurial will reply with:

   ```
   marked working directory as branch newbranch
   (branches are permanent and global, did you want a bookmark?)
   ```

   (the second sentence is omitted if there are already open branches other than `default`).
2. Making a new commit.

Until you execute step 2, the branch you "made" with `hg branch` does not exist: it's simply the *idea* of a branch.  This idea is saved along with the state of the working-tree.

Note that whenever you create a new commit, the new commit has a parent commit (or occasionally two parents, when concluding a merge).  The ID of the parent of the new commit is the ID of the current commit, i.e., revision `.`.  This is why you must first update to the desired revision.

The work-tree is, in effect, a *proposed commit*.  Until you make it differ from the *current* commit, though, there's no change-set to commit.  (If you are familiar with Git, this is similar to its internals, though there are some key differences.  In Git, the current revision is named `HEAD` rather than `.`, and instead of the work-tree being the proposed commit, Git uses its "index" as the proposed commit.  More critically, in Git, a commit is on some number of different branches simultaneously, so except for two special cases, Git creates the branch name immediately, rather than later once there's a commit for it.  This is because the new branch and old branch share all the old branch's commits—a peculiar sort of madness, though it all works out in the end.)

This shows up in the output of `hg summary`, which describes:

- the ID of the parent your new changeset would have if you made the commit now, i.e., the revision ID of revision `.`;
- the name of the current branch (the branch itself may not exist yet);
- the work-tree state as compared to revision `.`;
- the distance `.` has from the current head(s) of the current branch (the branch containing `.`);
- the number of draft and secret phase commits, if there are any;
- and a few optional additional bits of information.

A *head* in Mercurial is any commit with no descendant commits in the same branch.  Updating to an old revision that is not itself a head, then creating a new commit, will automatically create a new head, increasing the number of heads by one.  If that new head is in an existing branch, the existing branch's number of heads likewise increases by one.  If that new head results in the creation of a new branch, the new branch now springs into existence and has one commit, which is a head commit.

To create a new named branch, this last is just what you want.  So you need to update to the starting revision—this can be an existing branch head, if you like—and then switch to the new branch, which does not actually exist yet.  You can then make a commit to create the branch, whose single revision is the new branch's head.  (If the previous commit was a, or the, head of the old branch, it remains a head.)

Comment: Strangely I was able to create the new branch just by pushing in SourceTree. I might have switched between branches a few times before getting it to work.